# How to make an OR statement in python?

Tags: python

Why does this not work:

```
            file = "v3a2"
            if "v1" or "v2" in file:
                v1.write(total)
            elif "v3" in file:
                print "never here?????"
```

How to formulate this?

Comment: Non-empty strings are 'true-ish' on their own, so `if "v1"` is returning True.

Comment: if v1 in file or v2 in file, works

Comment: To add some more clarification on what's going on: your condition gets parsed as `if ("v1") or ("v2" in file): ...`, and every object in Python has some sort of truth value.

Comment: A few weeks ago I was having same type of problem, I just asked that into Python Tutor mailing list. You can also see that conversation here : http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tutor/89596/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
        if "v1" or "v2" in file:
```

is equivalent to

```
        if ("v1") or ("v2" in file):
```

Which will always be `True` because `bool("v1")==True`

you could say

```
        if any(x in file for x in ["v1", "v2"]):
```

or

```
        if "v1" in file or "v2" in file:
```

The version with `any` looks nicer if there are more than 2 or 3 items to check

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
 if "v1" in file or "v2" in file:
```

instead of

```
 if "v1" or "v2" in file:
```

Perhaps a review of Python [Boolean Operations](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) might be helpful. At the bottom of that page in the summary there is also a *table of operator precedence*. If you consult you the table, you can see that since the `in` operator  has a higher precedence than `or` operator, the expression is interpreted like this:

```
if ("v1") or ("v2" in file):
```

rather than what you expected/intended.

Also note that, as @sepp2k mentions in a helpful comment below, that if `or` had a higher precedence than `in`, your expression would end up as `if ("v1" or "v2") in file:` which also would not work the way you intended.

Here is a direct link to another [table of operator precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) since I couldn't find one for the above.

Comment: Note that if the operator precedence were different and it'd be parsed as `if ("v1" or "v2") in file:`, that'd still not do what the OP wants. So that's only half the issue.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, that's a good point, thanks for mentioning this too.

Comment: @sepp2k I paraphrased your comment and updated my answer, I hope that's ok with you (since not everyone reads all the comments).

Comment: +1 see gnibbler's use of any() below for a nicer looking solution.

Comment: @jorrebor I updated my answer with some additional information that might be useful.